# External HDD working on Ubuntu Live CD but not Ubuntu server

Tags: server, usb, mount, hard-drive

I have an external USB 3.0 drive that works when plugged into a Windows 8 machine and when running an Ubuntu live CD. It will mount and is accessible as both FAT32 and EXT4 in the live CD.

When plugged into the same server running Ubuntu server it will show up with no name in lsusb and running the command "sudo fdisk -l" only the SSD in the server displays.

I've tried 2 different enclosures and am at my wits end. I can't figure out what is so different with regards to usb between Ubuntu Server and Ubuntu Desktop that one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: So I was able to resolve this by reverting back to the 3.13 kernel. For some reason the 3.15 kernel hates these 3.0 drive enclosures. Worked perfectly once I did

Answer (score 1):

Answered already above. Reverted to 3.13 kernel